# Why is the result of Decimal.MaxValue - 0.5 an integer?

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

I was playing with decimal today. I noticed this:

```
Decimal.MaxValue 
79228162514264337593543950335

Decimal.MaxValue - 0.5m
79228162514264337593543950334
```

The following code prints true.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimal d = Decimal.MaxValue - 0.5M;
            var b = d % 1 == 0;
            Console.WriteLine(b);

        }
```

I am sure there is a reason behind this but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The decimal type uses 96 bits to store the sequence of digits ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx)), plus a sign (1 bit) and a scaling factor that specifies the location of the decimal place.

For this decimal number:

```
79228162514264337593543950335
```

All 96 bits are used to the left of the decimal point - there's nothing left to represent the fractional part of the answer. So, it gets rounded.

If you divide the number by 10:

```
7922816251426433759354395033.5
```

Then you have a few bits available to represent the fractional part - but only to 1/10, no finer.

The key difference between `decimal` and `double`/`float` is that it is based on a *decimal* scaling factor specifying the location of a *decimal point*; the other floating types are based on a *binary* scaling factor specifying the location of a *binary point*.

Comment: If you were right about the result being rounded instead of the operands, the result would be 79228162514264337593543950335 not 79228162514264337593543950334, because 79228162514264337593543950334.5 rounds upwards.

Comment: I did some calculation myself and this answer sounds correct.

Comment: @Anton - the `decimal` type is primarily intended for handling amounts of money/currency, one area where people tend to notice the flaws of double/float. For that reason, `decimal` uses *Bankers Rounding* (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding). Why? Always rounding 0.5 up gives a statistical bias that causes a small amount of overstating, especially significant when totalling a column of rounded values. Bankers rounding avoids this by rounding 0.5 to the *nearest even value*. So, 3.5 rounds to 4.0; 4.5 also rounds to 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

`0.5` is being rounded before subtraction. `decimal` strives to make the result as precise as possible, so the operation becomes `79228162514264337593543950335 - 00000000000000000000000000000.5`. But `0.5` cannot be represented as a `decimal` of the required precision and is rounded upwards to `1`.

Comment: The decimal type is perfectly able to represent 0.5m.

Comment: I said "0.5 cannot be represented as a decimal of the required precision", which is different from "0.5 cannot be represented as a decimal".

Answer (score 0):

It is not an integer, it *is* in fact a `Decimal`.

Integers (Int32) can have values from negative 2,147,483,648 positive 2,147,483,647.

As you can see, this is well out of these ranges.

In term of the display and accuracy, `79228162514264337593543950334.5` cannot be represented by `Decimal`.

Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for more details (What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic).

Comment: Integer and `int`/`Int32` aren't necessarily synonyms.

Comment: -1 because following code prints True.

decimal d = Decimal.MaxValue - 0.5M;
b = d % 1 == 0;
Console.WriteLine(b);

Comment: @chikak - That doesn't make it an integer. `var d = decimal.MaxValue - 0.5M; Console.WriteLine(typeof(decimal).ToString());` prints out `System.Decimal`.

Comment: @Oded, @chikak: You're arguing about semantics. An integer is a whole number. The result in this case is an integer but it's stored in a `decimal` variable. If I type `decimal foo = 9876543210;` then `foo` is a `decimal`, but that doesn't magically mean that `9876543210` is no longer an integer.

Comment: I know it is a decimal and can't fit into an int variable. What I meant was that the result should have a decimal point in it. 
Why can't 79228162514264337593543950334.5 fit into a decimal? I am reading the link you gave but it is a bit long document :-)

Comment: @LukeH I agree with your comment.